# Teleport to Object not working

Tags: objects

When I pressed <kbd>.</kbd> it didn't teleport me to the object, can someone help fix this problem? I selected it and then pressed <kbd>.</kbd>.

[image: selected object in outliner]

Answer (score 1):

The active object needs to be on a visible layer in order for *View Selected* (<kbd>.</kbd>) to work.

Look in the 3D view header at the layers.
[image: layers in the 3D view header]

As shown in that picture, I suspect you will have the active object on a non visible layer. The darker squares are the visible layers. The orange dot is the active object.

Press <kbd>`</kbd> to show all layers, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> on the layer button in the 3D view header for the layer the active object in on.

Answer (score 0):

Just go onto Material mode at the bottom.